# How did we to get that value?

Tags: prolog

So hello prolog geniuses :)  let's consider the given database:

```
q3(t(V, nul, nul), 0).
q3(t(V, Q, nul), 1).
q3(t(V, nul, Q), 1).
q3(t(V, Q1, Q2), T) :- q3(Q1, T1), q3(Q2, T2), T is 1+T1+T2.
```

and the following query

```
?- q3(t(4,
 t(2,
 nul,
t(3, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul))),
 t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)),
 t(9, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul)))),T).
```

Why is the answer 5? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what structure `t(_, _, _)` represents, and what the result of `q3` represents?

Comment: t(root, leftChild, rightChild) (a Binary Tree)!, hopefully it was your question :)

Comment: The answer that `q3` gives isn't just 5. This particular predicate produces multiple solutions: 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6,  7, and 7.

Comment: correct but on that particular question one answer was enough, i was mostly interested on the  "algorithm" used to solve this case which clemos gave brilliantly ! from there it's pretty clear that we backtrack to find other solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q3(t(4,t(2,nul,t(3, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul))),t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), t(9, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul)))),T).
    V = 4
    Q1 = t(2,nul,t(3, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul)))
        V = 2
        Q1 = nul
        Q2 != nul
    => T1 = 1

    Q2 = t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), t(9, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul)))
        V = 7
        Q1 = t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul))
            V = 5
            Q1 = nul
            Q2 != nul
        => T1 = 1

        Q2 = t(9, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul))
            V = 9
            Q1 = t(1,nul,nul)
            => T1 = 0
            Q2 = t(9,nul,nul)
            => T2 = 0
        => T2 = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1
    => T2 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

=> T = 1 + 1 + 3 = 5.
```

Comment: What is this program supposed to do?

Comment: It was just a question on an old midterm, they asked for the output, of the given query of course!

Answer (score 2):

The predicate doesn't just yield 5 as an answer. If you run it, it yields several answers: 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, and 7.

The structure, `t(V, L, R)` represents a binary tree. Reformatting the query to make it a little more visible:

```
q3( t(4,
         t(2,
             nul,
             t(3,
                  t(1, nul, nul),
                  t(9, nul, nul)
              )
          ),
          t(7,
                t(5,
                     nul,
                     t(6, nul, nul)
                 ),
                t(9,
                     t(1, nul, nul),
                     t(9, nul, nul)
                 )
           )
     ),
  T).
```

Or, to lay the first argument more like a "tree", so we can visualize it:

```
        _______4_______
       /               \
      2             ____7____
     / \           /         \
    n  _3_        5          _9_
      /   \      / \        /   \
     1     9    n   6      1     9
    / \   / \      / \    / \   / \
   n   n n   n    n   n  n   n n   n
```

Now let's consider the rules defined by `q3`:

```
1) q3(t(V, nul, nul), 0).
```

> A node that has no child nodes counts as zero (0). It doesn't count.

```
2) q3(t(V, Q, nul), 1).
3) q3(t(V, nul, Q), 1).
```

> A node that has *at least one* nul child counts as 1

```
4) q3(t(V, Q1, Q2), T) :-
    q3(Q1, T1),
    q3(Q2, T2),
    T is 1+T1+T2.
```

> A node that has two children (regardless of what they are) counts as 1 plus the sum of the quantity given for each the two children.

We can see from these definitions of the predicate clauses any node that has two nul children will satisfy clauses 1, 2, or 3. So each such node could potentially contribute to 3 solutions on backtracking. However, predicates 2 and 3 will "prune" solutions below nodes that have exactly one nul child. There's only one branch of the tree that doesn't have the only-one-null child, and that's the branch starting with node value 9. Each of the sub-branches, since they have two nul nodes, contributes 3 solutions. So that's 3x3 or 9 total solutions that emerge, which is what we see (5, 6,  6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7 and 7).

To determine where 5 comes from, which is the first solution, you just need to see which clause succeeds first for each node.

```
Node@4: matches rule 4: 1 + Node@2 + Node@7
Node@2: matches rule 3: 1
Node@7: matches rule 4: 1 + Node@5 + Node@9
Node@5: matches rule 3: 1
Node@9: matches rule 4: 1 + Node@1 + Node@9
Node@1: matches rule 1: 0
Node@9: matches rule 1: 0
```

If we add these up, we get: Node@4 sums to 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 5 (really just counting up the 1's in the above). Backtracking where other rules will also match yields the other 8 values.

---

It looks like `q3` is attempting to count nodes, but doing so incorrectly. To do this correctly, let's start over with defining the rules:

> If a node is nul, it should count as zero

```
q3(nul, 0).
```

> If a node is not null, then the count of nodes should be the sum of the count of nodes of the left and right branches, plus 1 for the current node

```
q3(t(_, L, R), C) :- q3(L, CL), q3(R, CR), C is 1 + CL + CR.
```

Using these two clauses, we get:

```
| ?- q3(t(4,
 t(2,
 nul,
t(3, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul))),
 t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)),
 t(9, t(1,nul,nul), t(9,nul,nul)))),T).

T = 11

yes
| ?-
```

One solution, 11, which is the count of nodes.

Comment: Thanks for this deep answer!! very useful! another cup of coffee for 3 more hours of prolog :)

Comment: @ApexPredator coffee indeed helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be to do the following:

```
?- trace(q3/2), trace(is/2).
%         q3/2: [call,redo,exit,fail]
%         (is)/2: [call,redo,exit,fail]
true.

[debug]  ?- q3(t(4,                   % <- (6)
                 t(2,                 % <- (7)
                   nul,               % (7) -> 1
                   t(3,               % .
                     t(1,nul,nul),    % .
                     t(9,nul,nul))),  % .
                 t(7,                 % <- (7)
                   t(5,               % <- (8)
                     nul,             % (8) -> 1
                     t(6, nul, nul)), % .
                   t(9,               % <- (8)
                     t(1,nul,nul),    % (9) -> 0
                     t(9,nul,nul)     % (9) -> 0
                     )                % 1 + 0 + 0 = 1 (8) -> 1
                    )                 % 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 (7) -> 3
                   ),                 % 1 + 1 + 3 = 5 (6) -> 5
               T).
 T Call: (6) q3(t(4, t(2, nul, t(3, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul))), t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), t(9, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul)))), _G386)
 T Call: (7) q3(t(2, nul, t(3, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul))), _G538)
 T Exit: (7) q3(t(2, nul, t(3, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul))), 1)
 T Call: (7) q3(t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), t(9, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul))), _G538)
 T Call: (8) q3(t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), _G538)
 T Exit: (8) q3(t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), 1)
 T Call: (8) q3(t(9, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul)), _G538)
 T Call: (9) q3(t(1, nul, nul), _G538)
 T Exit: (9) q3(t(1, nul, nul), 0)
 T Call: (9) q3(t(9, nul, nul), _G538)
 T Exit: (9) q3(t(9, nul, nul), 0)
 T Call: (9) _G543 is 1+0+0
 T Exit: (9) 1 is 1+0+0
 T Exit: (8) q3(t(9, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul)), 1)
 T Call: (8) _G549 is 1+1+1
 T Exit: (8) 3 is 1+1+1
 T Exit: (7) q3(t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), t(9, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul))), 3)
 T Call: (7) _G386 is 1+1+3
 T Exit: (7) 5 is 1+1+3
 T Exit: (6) q3(t(4, t(2, nul, t(3, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul))), t(7, t(5, nul, t(6, nul, nul)), t(9, t(1, nul, nul), t(9, nul, nul)))), 5)
T = 5 .
```

While formatting the term, seeing what `q3/2` is going to do with it is not too difficult. The predicate is short enough and you can do the pattern-matching by eye. But of course you can also look through the very detailed trace. You will notice on the tree that some sub-trees are not explored at all at this first search for a solution.